# All roots of a polynomial in ring $F_2+uF_2+u^2F_2$, where $u^3=0$

Tags: irreducible-polynomials, coding-theory, primitive-roots, galois-extensions, finite-rings

Let $R=F_2+uF_2+u^2F_2$, where $u^3=0$, be a finite commutative ring. So $R=\{0,1,u,v,uv,u^2,v^2,v^3\}$, where $v=1+u$, $v^2=1+u^2$, $v^3=1+u+u^2$, $uv=u+u^2$. It is well known that

$$x^7-1=(x+v^3)(x^3+uvx^2+v^2x+v^3)(x^3+vx^2+ux+v^3),$$

where all  factors in decomposition are basic irreducible polynomials over $R$. Since $x^3+uvx^2+v^2x+v^3$ is a basic primitive polynomial over $R,$ the root $\alpha$ of this polynomial is a primitive element of the extension  $R[x]/(x^3+uvx^2+v^2x+v^3).$

In polynomials over fileds, we can find all roots by cyclotomic cosets. But I do not know How can calculate all roots of $x^3+uvx^2+v^2x+v^3$ in ring $R$? Are  roots of polynomial $x^3+vx^2+ux+v^3$ as  some powers of $\alpha$? how can i calculate them?

Any hints will be appreciated.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not familiar with the meaning of *a basic irreducible polynomial over $R$* not with *a primitive element of the extension*. I have seen both of these in the context of Galois fields/rings though. Can you clarify?

Comment: I think there is something wrong with your factorization of $x^7-1$. If I expand the right hand side, the degree six term gets the coefficient
$$v^3+uv+v=(1+u+u^2)+(u+u^2)+(1+u)=u\neq0.$$

Comment: Also with the constant term $v^9$. We have $v^8=(1+u)^8=1+u^8=1$. Therefore $v^9=v\neq 1$.